# How do pthreads cause a segmentation fault in c (despite not allocating memory)?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads

So I'm trying to iterate recursively through some given directory and copy all the contents of each file within each subdirectory to an output file. I'm required to create a new thread to copy the file as well as to iterate any subdirectories. What I do is iterate through a directory given from the terminal. With each call to iterate_dir, an array of pthreads is created and a counter for it, so I can close the directory after all threads created have been joined. So if a subdirectory was found, I create a pthread to call iterate_dir and pass it a new path, grow the pthread array by one and store the created pthread in it. If a file was found, I create a pthread to call copy_file, which opens the file reads its content, storing each character into a shared string (which is mutexed and dynamic in size). However, I keep getting some unexplained segmentation fault. I input a directory with 2 files and 2 subdirectories, with 1 subdirectory being empty, and the other containing 1 file. I tried removing copy_file and with it the pthread that called it, but I still got a segfault. I tried removing the array of pthreads I created, yet it still segfaulted. I tried stepping through it using gdb to no conclusive answer. I'll provide both cases, one without copy_file and the pthread array, one with them. They both segfault. My question is, how does a pthread segfault despite not even allocating anything (as is the case with the code without copy_file and the pthread array)? I'm really puzzled and was wondering if anyone had any ideas or even advice on any of the other code. Thanks.

Without pthread array and copy_file (EASIER TO READ)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void* iterate_dir(void* args);


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    char current_path[strlen(argv[1])+1];
    strcpy(current_path,argv[1]);


    pthread_t start;
    pthread_create(&start,NULL,&iterate_dir,current_path);
    pthread_join(start,NULL);

}



void* iterate_dir(void *args){


    DIR *dd = opendir((char*)args);
    struct dirent *curr;


    while((curr = readdir(dd))!=NULL){

        if(curr->d_type==DT_DIR && (strcmp(curr->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(curr->d_name,"..")==0)){

            continue;

        }   

        if(curr->d_type==DT_DIR){


            char new_path[strlen(curr->d_name)+strlen((char*)args)+2];
            sprintf(new_path,"%s/%s",(char*)args,curr->d_name);
            pthread_t new_thread;
            pthread_create(&new_thread,NULL,&iterate_dir,new_path);


        }else{



        }


    }


    return NULL;

}
```

With copy_file and pthread array (HARDER TO READ)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

void* iterate_dir(void* args);
void* copy_file(void* args);

pthread_mutex_t mut_for_final_string;
pthread_mutex_t mut_for_current_string_position;
char* final_string;
int current_string_position;


int main(int argc, char** argv){

    char current_path[strlen(argv[1])+1];
    strcpy(current_path,argv[1]);
    char new_file_path[strlen(argv[2])+15+1];
    sprintf(new_file_path,"%s/%s",argv[2],"AllFiles-sorted");
    int output = open(new_file_path, O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0666);

    final_string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    current_string_position = 0;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mut_for_final_string,NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&mut_for_current_string_position,NULL);

    pthread_t start;
    pthread_create(&start,NULL,&iterate_dir,current_path);
    pthread_join(start,NULL);

    write(output,final_string,current_string_position);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut_for_final_string);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut_for_current_string_position);

}


void* copy_file(void *args){

    int input = open((char*)args,O_RDONLY);
    char c;

    while(read(input,&c,1)>0){

        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut_for_final_string);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut_for_current_string_position);
        final_string[current_string_position] = c;
        char* tmp = NULL;
        tmp = realloc(final_string,(current_string_position)+2);
        while(tmp==NULL){}
        final_string = tmp;
        (current_string_position)++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut_for_current_string_position);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut_for_final_string);

    }

    close(input);

    return NULL;

}


void* iterate_dir(void *args){


    DIR *dd = opendir((char*)args);
    struct dirent *curr;
    pthread_t* tids = (pthread_t*)malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));
    int tids_counter = 0;



    while((curr = readdir(dd))!=NULL){

        if(curr->d_type==DT_DIR && (strcmp(curr->d_name,".")==0 || strcmp(curr->d_name,"..")==0)){

            continue;

        }   

        if(curr->d_type==DT_DIR){


            char new_path[strlen(curr->d_name)+strlen((char*)args)+2];
            sprintf(new_path,"%s/%s",(char*)args,curr->d_name);
            pthread_t new_thread;
            pthread_create(&new_thread,NULL,&iterate_dir,new_path);
            tids[tids_counter] = new_thread;
            tids_counter++;

            pthread_t* tmp_ptr = NULL;
            tmp_ptr = realloc(tids, (sizeof(pthread_t)*(tids_counter+1)));
            while(tmp_ptr==NULL){}
            tids = tmp_ptr;


        }else{

            char old_path[strlen(curr->d_name)+strlen((char*)args)+2];
            sprintf(old_path,"%s/%s",(char*)args,curr->d_name);
            pthread_t new_thread;
            pthread_create(&new_thread,NULL,&copy_file,old_path);
            tids[tids_counter] = new_thread;
            tids_counter++;

            pthread_t* tmp_ptr = NULL;
            tmp_ptr = realloc(tids, (sizeof(pthread_t)*(tids_counter+1)));
            while(tmp_ptr==NULL){}
            tids = tmp_ptr;


        }


    }

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<tids_counter;i++){

        pthread_join(tids[i],NULL);

    }

    closedir(dd);

    return NULL;

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char new_path[strlen(curr->d_name)+strlen((char*)args)+2];
```

This memory address is invalid as soon as you leave the scope it was declared in, yet you pass that address to a new pthread.

Comment: I'm confused then. I ran the code without using pthreads at all (just simply making a call to iterate_dir instead of creating a pthread for it) and it works completely fine. So its within the scope when a make a recursive call but not when a make a call using a pthread?

Comment: @DevinM `pthread_create` "immediately" returns, and the thread that called `pthread_create` continues to execute. `new_path` is only valid for as long as the calling thread stays in the `if(curr->d_type==DT_DIR){ ... }` block. If you replace `pthread_create` with a call to `iterate_dir`, then you only have one thread of execution and the calling thread waits for `iterate_dir` to return before it continues on, all the while it's waiting in the `if(curr->d_type==DT_DIR){ ... }` block so `new_path` is still in scope.

Comment: "and it works completely fine", yes because you have only one thread when executing. cleblanc says that you should pass the memory address to the executing thread.

Comment: Ok I used malloc to create each string I pass and it seemed to do the trick. Thanks for the help and explanations!